# XGBoost with AutoML in Flow

Tags: h2o

I have fitted various H2O models, including XGBoost, in R and also within Flow, predicting count data (non-negative integers).

I can fit XGBoost models in Flow from the "Model" menu. However, I would like to include XGBoost when using AutoML - however XGBoost is not listed. The available algorithms are:

```
GLM
DRF
GBM
DeepLearning
StackedEnsemble
```

The response column is coded as INT, and the version details are:

```
H2O Build git branch    rel-wright
H2O Build git hash  0457fda98594a72aca24d06e8c3622d45bd545d2
H2O Build git describe  jenkins-rel-latest-stable-1-g0457fda
H2O Build project version   3.20.0.8
H2O Build age   1 month and 15 days
H2O Built by    jenkins
H2O Built on    2018-09-21 16:54:12
H2O Internal Security   Disabled
Flow version    0.7.36
```

How can I include XGBoost when running AutoML in Flow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XGBoost has only been recently added to AutoML (you can see the changes for each version here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md).

If you would like to have access to XGBoost within H2OAutoML please upgrade to the latest version, which is currently 3.22.0.1: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xia/1/index.html